# Existe algun emulador iOS para Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ios, ubuntu, react-native

Estoy comenzando a desarrollar aplicaciones en `React Native`, tengo ubuntu `16.04 LTS`, y tengo el problema de que no puedo instalar `Xcode` ya que no tengo una `mac`, uso `GenyMotion` para emular el sistema `android` y probar en ese `SO`, mi pregunta es, existe alguna manera de emular un dispositivo `iOS` en `ubuntu` para pruebas durante el desarrollo?. gracias de antemano.

Comment: Instalando una maquina virtual

Comment: no he conseguido una `iso` de un sistema `iOS` para montarlo en `virtual box` siquiera. Tu usas alguna?

Comment: no, y ahi tendras la dificultad, encontrar esa imagen. Pero para trabajar con Mac, tienes que tener Mac.

Comment: claro, pero intento buscar otra solución al menos para las pruebas durante el desarrollo por que no tengo `mac.`

Comment: @Spidvmp pero instalar una VM con OSX no viola la licencia del OS?

Answer (score 2):

Para que tengas una buena experiencia de desarrollo lo mejor sería usar 
*una Mac

Pero si no es accesible en estos momentos podrías usar 
"browser stack

> Una alternativa para  probar tu aplicación en cualquier dispositivo y navegador

Comment: No entiendo por qué votan negativa esta respuesta. Atiende al problema que indica quien pregunta y le da dos opciones para resolver su problema.